# gTTS unable to save file twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, text-to-speech

I am attempting to use gTTS as a realistic text to speech module for a personal assistant project. When querying the google service I am able to save the mp3 file and run it with pygame.

```
from pygame import mixer
from gtts import gTTS    

def speak(data):
    tts = gTTS(text=data, lang='en')
    tts.save('speech.mp3')
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load('speech.mp3')
    mixer.music.play()
```

Upon running the function "speak" once it succesfully outputs, however when running it again it fails with an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\project_ai\assistant.py", line 7, in <module>
    text_to_speech.main('hello')
  File "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\project_ai\modules\speech_text_synthesis\text_to_speech.py", line 8, in main
    tts.save('speech.mp3')                                                                                                                                       File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\gtts\tts.py", line 246, in save
    with open(savefile, 'wb') as f:                                                                                                                                   PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'speech.mp3'
```

The error happens when attempting to save the text to another mp3 again. Thus pygame is unable to play it. I am aware that I can simply change the name of the file to save it but I would rather not. How am I able to accomplish this?

Comment: I guess it's beacuse the is still locked. Have you tried calling `pygame.mixer.music.stop()` before `tts.save`?

Comment: yes, however the program still returns a permission error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally... success...

I have been researching this problem for several hours.  I've tried multiple different sound players in addition to PyGame (pyaudio, playsound, pyglet, ...).  I went down the same road everyone else had been down.

And then.... it hit me... a different road... **Use TWO filenames.** (a technique called double-buffering).

While I didn't use this particular code, I thought I should present an answer using your code....

```
from pygame import mixer
from gtts import gTTS    

count = 0

def speak(data):
    global count

    tts = gTTS(text=data, lang='en')
    tts.save(f'speech{count%2}.mp3')
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load(f'speech{count%2}.mp3')
    mixer.music.play()
    count += 1
```

The reason it works is that the TTS library will release the previous file when it switches to the new one.  The problem we were facing when trying to use 1 filename is that we struggled to find a way to get the file resource freed up.  This method frees it when you switch to the other filename.

Enjoy internet!  Go make some cool programs!

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is a common problem with pygame, at least I found some deleted questions on SO about this topic.

Try loading the file via a memory mapped file after saving instead of using just the filename, like this:

```
import mmap
...
def speak(data):
    tts = gTTS(text=data, lang='en')
    tts.save('speech.mp3')
    with open('speech.mp3') as f: 
        m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) 

    pygame.mixer.music.load(m) 
    pygame.mixer.music.play() 

    m.close()
```

Using the context manager ensures the file is actually closed after copying into memory, and `pygame.mixer.music.load` will not touch the file at all.